# How to configure and setup piwik in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I want to configure and setup piwik in Magento 2 based on custom data.

I refered this module. [Click Here](https://github.com/henkelund/magento2-henhed-piwik)

But, not understand how to manage with Magento 2.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install the module?

Comment: Yes.............

Comment: please check the configuration section, you may need to enter some API keys

Comment: I want to display custom data instead of orders etc.

Comment: if you could post screenshots, i would be helpful, I have not used that extension to suggest something..